# jQuery не работает на странице jsp

Tags: jquery, jsp

Доброй ночи!
Пытаюсь разобраться как работает jQuery но не могу его нормально настроить на jsp странице. На странице html код работает нормально. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            var flowers = ["Астра", "Нарцисс", "Роза", "Пион", "Примула",
         "Подснежник", "Мак", "Первоцвет", "Петуния", "Фиалка"];
            
            $('#acInput').autocomplete({
                source: flowers
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <label for="acInput">Выберите название цветка: </label>
            <input id="acInput"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ваша jsp -страница генерирует точно такой же код, как вы привели?

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос. Я создаю jsp страницу с кодом, приведенным выше. Браузер отображает поле ввода но автоподстановка не работает.

Comment: Ок, что вы видите в консоли браузера? Попробуйте подключать библиотеки, добавив `http://`в начале.

Comment: О чудо :) оно заработало. http помогло, хотя ранее я пробовал https. Куда тут тыцать за правильный ответ? Может еще подскажете, если у меня в перечне нет введенного слова, я могу его передавать на обработку?

Comment: Добавил ответ. Слово не из списка можно передавать на обработку, autocomplete только дополняет вам слова при вводе, на передачу параметров на сервер он не влияет.

Comment: все же столкнулся с проблемой, что слово не из списка не отправляется. Может подскажете в чем проблема?                                       <spring:bind path="name" >
<form:input id="acInput" type="text" path="name" class="form-inline"
                         placeholder='Name${name}' autofocus="true"></form:input>

    </spring:bind>

Comment: Без скрипта автодополнения форма отправляется? Я не вижу причин, почему она может не отправляться, разве что у вас какие-то ошибки в консоли браузера появляются.

Comment: как не странно, пока попил чай оно заработало. Но вываливает весь список. Пишут, что если ресурсы предоставляются удаленно, то необходимо сортировку реализовывать тоже удаленно. А можно как-то все-таки включить сортировку в скрипте?

Comment: Разве что предварительно получить данные, отсортировать их, а потом уже с ними отсортированными вызвать autocomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте подключать библиотеки, добавив `http://` в начале.